# Finding the locus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $Z$ be a complex number then the locus represented by $|Z-1| + |Z+2| = 2$ is?

How could we show effectively that no complex number satisfies this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the most important thing is to understand meaning of modulus value. $|z-a|$ is the distance between $z$ and $a \in \mathbb C$. Now imaine the argand plane. You are asked to find $z$ such that sum of distances of $z$ from $1$ and $-2$ is equal to $2$. Now the minimum sum of distance is when $z$ lies on the line joining these two complex numbers(by triangle law). But distance between these two numbers is $3$, hence the value of LHS can't be less than $3$. e are done.

It would help if you plot these points on argand plane. $1$ is $(1,0$ and so on.

You might want to try something more general. Try to find locus for general constant $c \in \mathbb R^+$.

Now if $c=3$ what do you get?? 
What if $c > 3$??

> A straight line segment in first case. An ellipse in second.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for my poor English first~
Let's convert the problem in a more visually way.
In a two-dimensional model, real number on the horizontal axis and imaginary number on the vertical.

$|Z-1| + |Z+2| = 2$  means find a point ($Z$) in this plane while the sum distance of $Z$ to $(1,0)$ and $Z$ to $(-2,0)$ is $2$.

Obviously, the point $Z$ is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

TheJoker's answer in analytical form:
$$|3| = |2 + z - z + 1| \le |2 + z| + |1 - z| = |2|$$
by the triangle inequality. Contradiction.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant.. Just wanted him to do this work . :-P